# classmethod and helper functions inside a python class

Tags: python, oop, decorator

My goal is to reduce some of the redundancy in a class that I have created.  I've simplified the problem into a very simple example

### My current Class

```
class BigNumbers(object):
      def __init__(self, big_number):
            self.number = big_number

      @classmethod
      def make_with_sums(cls, sum_to):
            fin_num = 0

            for i in range(1, sum_to):
                  fin_num += i

            return cls( fin_num )

      @classmethod
      def make_with_product(cls, mul_to):
            fin_num = 1

            for i in range(1, mul_to):
                  fin_num *= i

            return cls( fin_num )
```

### My Desired Class (DNRY)

```
class dnryNumbers(object):
      def __init__(self, big_number):
            self.number = big_number

      @classmethod
      def _make_with_helper(cls, make_meth, fin_num):
            method_dict = {'sum': lambda x, y: x + y,
                           'prod': lambda x, y: x * y
                           }
            var = 0
            for i in range(1, fin_num):
                  var = method_dict[make_meth](var, i)

            return cls( var )

      def make_with_sums(self, sum_to):

            return self._make_with_helper( 'sum', sum_to )

      def make_with_product(self, mul_to):

            return self._make_with_helper('prod', mul_to )
```

My goals is to use the same function invocations as I would when using my `BigNumbers` class, such as:

```
In [60]: bn = BigNumbers.make_with_product(10)

In [61]: bn.number
Out[61]: 362880
```

-- OR --

```
In [63]: bn = BigNumbers.make_with_sums(10)

In [64]: bn.number
Out[64]: 45
```

But that current functionality doesn't work:

```
In [65]: bn = dnryNumbers.make_with_product(10)
TypeError: unbound method make_with_product() must be called with dnryNumbers instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

Comment: you must also make these methods be classmethods and call cls._make_with_helpers(args)

Comment: Your example appears to have some issues: the dnryNumbers.make_with_product method isn't a classmethod, for example. Is this intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution 1:

```
bn = dnryNumbers(5)
bn.make_with_product(10)
```

solution 2:

```
@classmethod
def make_with_product(cls, mul_to):
    return cls._make_with_helper('prod', mul_to )
```

Comment: edited, because you must use cls and not self in a classmethod

Comment: Is it preferable to use `self` or `cls` as the argument to the function? IOW, `make_with_product(cls, mul_to)` --or-- `make_with_product(self, mul_to)`?

Comment: @benjaminmgross It denpends on what type of method the function is. For usual method use `self`, for classmethod use `cls`.

Comment: if it is decorated with @classmethod, you MUST pass cls and refer to the other class methods as cls.method_name. If it is not decorated, then you MUST pass self, and therefore MUST either call the classmethods using self.method_name or ClassName.method_name

Comment: I was thrown off because the origin (un-edited) answer had a @classmethod decoration but used `self` as the function argument. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer: `make_with_sums` and `make_with_products` are class methods, not instance methods, so they need to be declared as such. Also, note that `_make_with_helper` needs to take a *starting* value as an argument as well; initializing `var` to 0 is going to make `make_with_product` return `cls(0)` no matter what its arguments are.

`method_dict` is the same dictionary regardless of what inputs are passed to `_make_with_helper`, so it should be a class variable instead:

```
class dnryNumbers(object):
    def __init__(self, big_number):
        self.number = big_number

    method_dict = {'sum': lambda x, y: x + y,
                   'prod': lambda x, y: x * y
                  }

    @classmethod
    def _make_with_helper(cls, make_meth, fin_num, starting_value):          
        var = starting_value
        for i in range(1, fin_num):
              var = dnryNumbers.method_dict[make_meth](var, i)
        return cls( var )

    @classmethod
    def make_with_sums(cls, sum_to):
        return cls._make_with_helper('sum', sum_to, 0)

    @classmethod
    def make_with_product(cls, mul_to):
        return cls._make_with_helper('prod', mul_to, 1)
```

But now, `method_dict` is only adding an extra layer of indirection that you don't need. Since the functions are not intended to be used outside the class, just define them as "private" methods, and use references to them directly.

```
class dnryNumbers(object):
    def __init__(self, big_number):
        self.number = big_number

    @staticmethod
    def _sum(x, y):
        return x + y

    @staticmethod
    def _prod(x, y):
        return x * y

    @classmethod
    def _make_with_helper(cls, make_meth, fin_num, starting_value):        
        var = starting_value
        for i in range(1, fin_num):
              var = make_meth(var, i)
        return cls(var)
```

@classmethod
        def make_with_sums(cls, sum_to):
            return cls._make_with_helper(dnryNumbers._sum, sum_to, 0)

```
    @classmethod
    def make_with_product(cls, mul_to):
        return cls._make_with_helper(dnryNumbers._prod, mul_to, 1)
```

Finally, it's worth pointing out that unless your real code is more complicated than the example shown here, `_sum` is already available as `operator.add`, `_prod` is just `operator.mul`, and `_make_with_helper` is just a reimplementation of the `reduce` builtin (or `functools.reduce`, if Python 3).

```
import operator
try:
    reduce
except NameError:
    from functools import reduce

class dnryNumbers(object):
    def __init__(self, big_number):
        self.number = big_number

    @classmethod
    def _make_with_helper(cls, make_meth, fin_num, starting_value):
        return cls(reduce(make_meth, range(1, fin_num), starting_value))

    @classmethod
    def make_with_sums(cls, sum_to):
        return cls._make_with_helper(operator.add, sum_to, 0)

    @classmethod
    def make_with_product(cls, mul_to):
        return cls._make_with_helper(operator.add, mul_to, 1)
```